# Problem with received GPS data

Tags: rf, communication, gps

I am using an mtk3333 to read gps coords. I set nmea messages to only output gll data. The problem is that I am receiving the GLL packets but in this format:

$GNGLL,,,,,004912.869,V,N*6D

GLL packets format should look something like this:

[image]

So I am not receiving coordinates. And even the time doesnt make sense. I assume that's why the status field has a "V" for invalid data.
Any idea as to why this could be happenning ?

Comment: I would guess the antenna is not actually seeing satellites.  Is it placed somewhere with a clear view of the sky? GPS signals are very weak and easily blocked.  First time powered up, or after loss of power, it could be several minutes to acquire a satellite and download ephemeris data, which is then used on subsequent aquisitions for faster startups.

Comment: @CrossRoads I am indeed indoors. I imagined that that would cause some erros. Didnt think it would send incoherent data though. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: If it can't acquire a fix, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Not so much incoherent, just missing, hence all the commas.  I don't know why the N at the end vs  A or D.   Most devices will accept a time input message.  004912.869 looks valid: 00 hrs, 49 minutes, 12.869 seconds.

Comment: @CrossRoads It should be UTC though. At the time, that packet is very far from the correct time value. Right now I'm receiving 035648.869

Comment: @CrossRoads N stands for not valid. https://docs.novatel.com/OEM7/Content/Logs/GPGLL.htm#NMEAPositioningSystemModeIndicator
(Table at the end of the page)

Comment: @CrossRoads It turns out whenever I power the receiver down it starts counting from 00:00:00

Comment: "I set nmea messages to only output gll data."  I would suggest you set it to have the correct time vs the time since power on.  That may help with satellite acquisition also.  Or not, it may just update itself when it locates the first one.

Comment: @CrossRoads From what I read, the time field should contain the correct time not the time since "power on". So I assume it will update once it locates the sattelites.

Comment: Just give it a few minutes, or put it outside or near a window for some time. It'll probably start to receive data.

Comment: If the GPS is no battery backed up it will not have the correct time until it see a satellite, hence the 000000 time.